# Scrolling background with fixed content

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to scroll only the image in a fixed container? Or is there a way to scroll only the background image of an element?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white;
}

.header .image {
  transform: scale(1.03);
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.header .image img {
  filter: blur(5px);
}


.header .content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
}

.main {
  background-image: url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/80625/tree.jpg');
  width: 100%;
  height: 150vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/80625/tree.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="content">This header is fixed, but the image behind should scroll</div>
</div>
<div class="main"></div>
```

The goal is to have a frosted glass effect on the fixed bar. Since backdrop filters are currently not supported by most browsers, I am looking for an alternative.
In the end result, there will be a blurred image instead of a blur filter, to optimize performance (blur lags on mobile devices).

Answer (score 2):

Since it's the same image as in the content below it, you can simply erase the background-image and use an rgba color (including opacity) as a background color for that element:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgba(256, 256, 256, 0.5);
}

.header .image {
  transform: scale(1.03);
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.header .image img {
  filter: blur(5px);
}


.header .content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
}

.main {
  background-image: url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/80625/tree.jpg');
  width: 100%;
  height: 150vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">

  <div class="content">This header is fixed, but the image behind should scroll</div>
</div>
<div class="main"></div>
```